# How to convert a series of lines into a working HTML list?

Tags: search, html, line-break, replace

Right now, this is a task I find a lot easier in something like gedit, because I can just replace "\n" (the line break) with "</li>\n<li>" and then I have a list.

One of the few little things I don't seem to be able to in Emacs quickly, but something I use a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most direct way of doing this would be to

- Mark the region of text lines to become a list
- Press `M-%` (`query-replace`)
- Type `C-q C-j RET </li> C-q C-j <li> RET` (`C-q C-j` inserts a quoted newline character)
- Press `!` to replace all occurrences

Comment: i had to change around the opening and closing tags, but this works, and i think i can make myself remember C-q C-j.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively to query replace you can go with [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el):

[image]

Also consider using something like this:

```
(defun wrap-html-tag (tagName)
  "Add a tag to beginning and ending of current word or text selection."
  (interactive "sEnter tag name: ")
  (let (p1 p2 inputText)
    (if (use-region-p)
        (progn
          (setq p1 (region-beginning) )
          (setq p2 (region-end) )
          )
      (let ((bds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
        (setq p1 (car bds) )
        (setq p2 (cdr bds) ) ) )

    (goto-char p2)
    (insert "</" tagName ">")
    (goto-char p1)
    (insert "<" tagName ">")
    ))
```

[source](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_html_insert_tags.html)

Comment: If you find yourself doing this sort of editing on a regular basis then I highly recommend the multiple-cursors package.  Sometimes I wonder how I ever got along without it.

Comment: @welldan97 How did you create that GIF?  Just curious…

Comment: @lunaryorn, via [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap) for OS X. I've heard Quicktime can be better, though I didn't try yet.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-%`). Replace `^\(.*\)$` with `<li>\1</li>`.

Answer (score 1):

For a full-featured solution, convert your text into an org-mode list and [export to HTML](http://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-export.html). Prefix lines with '* ', active `org-mode`, and run `org-html-export-to-html`.

Comment: "You really shouldn't be generating HTML using text manipulations"--I can think of many reasons one might want to do that (you can't always control your input).

Comment: Prefixing input lines with an '* ' isn't asking too much, is it?

Comment: I believe org-mode export is excellent for an automated solution, but I don't think discouraging basic text manipulation for html generation is helpful.

Comment: If you want to add that as an answer (prefix all lines with '*', activate `org-mode`, then export to HTML) then that's fine, but I don't think it makes sense to scold people for wanting "quick-and-dirty" HTML generation.

Comment: Fair enough; I've reworded it.